# You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0...' C# WP7 XNA

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, xna, mscorlib

I need to use `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` in my C# Windows Phone 7.1 `XNA` game application. For some reason I get this error and when I try to add `mscorlib`, `the name space cannot be found`... Is there any fix to this?

The type `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T0>` is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly `mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'......`

Comment: The title of your question is also the precise answer...

Comment: I'm unable to add the assembly. It cannot be found when I type "using mscorlib;" even though it's referenced.

Comment: My bad, I did not even consider if it was supported :(

Answer (score 1):

[System.Threading.Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not supported in WP7.1. You can either remove usage of tasks or move to the newer version of WP and use [Microsoft BCL](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl/1.1.6).

Subjective advice: ignore older versions of WP7 and develop for newest WP7 version, not so many people have WP7 ( compared to WP8 ) and even less have an older version of it.